# Pandas Dataframe to SQLite - AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, dataframe, sqlite

I have a Pandas data frame that I want to export to a SQLite db. The db has a datetime index and I suspect that might be an issue.

When I run this part of the code:

```
con = sqlite3.connect("pat_rec.db")
dfMid.to_sql(dfMid,con=con, flavor='sqlite', if_exists='replace')
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first attribute of `to_sql` is name of the SQL table. You're passing the data frame object again. If you want to use `dfMid` as the table name, you have to put it in quotes.

Thus, your code would become:

```
dfMid.to_sql('dfMid',con=con, flavor='sqlite', if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: Wow. That simple. Thanks you so much for the help Kristof.